# Set the event on button click? how to

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I have written code for kendo but I have to call a function on click event of grid button.

Here is my inline code

```
   { 'command': 'destroy', 'title': 'delete' , 'width': 50 , event:{click: 'delete'}},
```

but the delete event code is not called

```
    self.delete = function () {

    alert('abc');

 }
```

the function is under view model; I am not calling observable, I have to use

```
 dataSource.fetch(function() {
  var products = dataSource.data();
  dataSource.remove(products[0]);
 dataSource.sync();
  });
```

here is jsfiddle to my code  [click here to see code](https://jsfiddle.net/kkdj6mup/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kkdj6mup/  here is full code\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137571/generate-event-on-row-button-click-and-add-icon-how-to improvements and answer this

Comment: Please do not ask two question on the same subject - merge and delete

Comment: question are lil bit same but with improvement and more code ok i understand