# generate event on row button click and add icon? how to

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

Here is my HTML code:

```
     <div id="grdCurrencies"
             data-selectable="true"
             data-role="grid"
             data-pageable=" true"
             data-sortable=" true"
             data-columns='[
              { "field": "CurrencyCode", "width": 100 },
                { "field": "CurrencyName", "width": 100 }  ,
                 { field:"", template:"<i "class=" fa fa-trash-o grid-icon" data-bind="click: destroy"">del<"/"i>" , "width":40 }]'
             data-bind="source: dsProduct, events: {change: OnGridActiveRowChanged} "
             style=" height :500px;width:35%;">
        </div>
```

In the `template` field:`<a >del<a>`, I have to add an icon and also have to fire an event on-clicking icon for that in the link. I have to give class and event name on-click. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-template="mytemplate"` attribute in grid and following is the sample code of template. This might do the trick

```
<script id="mytemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text:CurrencyCode"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:CurrencyName"></td>
        <td class="text-center" width="13%">
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o" data-bind="click: removeRec"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```